# Efficient way of translating struct items avoiding switch-case in C

Tags: c, algorithm, switch-statement

I have the following situation: there is a struct with quite a number of data on it that are of different types. There is another struct with an integer member where I put the ID correspondent to the data of the first struct that I want. And there is a third struct which should carry that data on. For example:

```
struct MyData
{
    char data1;
    float data2;
    short data3;
    //...
};

struct MyRequest
{
    int desiredDataId;
};

struct DataValue
{
    long data;
};
```

In the system, I send a message to a part of it with a MyRequest telling "I want data X". Then the system should look to which correspondent buffer (MyData members) the requested Id corresponds; and then creates a DataValue and put the desired data (casted) to `data` member.

The point: the most obvious way of doing the part where the systems identifies which of the MyData members are being requested based on the Id of MyRequest is with a switch-case:

```
switch(MyRequest.desiredDataId)
{
    case 0: //Id correspondent to data1
        DataValue.data = (long) MyData.data1;
        break;
    case 1: //Id correspondent to data2
        DataValue.data = (long) MyData.data2;
        break;
    case 3: //Id correspondent to data3
        DataValue.data = (long) MyData.data1;
        break;
    //...
}
```

The problem: that is fine when the number of members inside MyData are small; but I need a solution for a very big MyData - for now, one that have something like 370 members, what would lead to a huge switch-case - 370 cases!

The question: is there any other way to do such mapping that uses less coding?

For the time being, another alternative that I though would be to create an array of `void*` that would map pointers to MyData (which are declared globally in my case). So instead of the huge switch case, I would have to set a huge array at first and then just call

```
DataValue.data = *(long)pointerArray[MyRequest.data]
```

The problem is that, despite avoiding the huge switch-case, now I have to face a huge array initialization, so not a "master solution".

Is there another viable alternative?

Note: Forgive me if I wrote a wrong C syntax; I was in a hurry to write this question :)

Comment: Sorry, but the `void*` solution is really the way to go here.  Besides, how is using a single array more huge then having 370 variables? Also, it looks like it should be `DataValue.data = (long)(*pointerArray[MyRequest.data])`, with the asterisk on the inside.

Comment: Another question: Why are you storing the values in all different data types, if you are just casting them to `long` anyway?

Comment: If this is about keeping the list of struct members in sync with the switch, then the [X Macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) might help.

Comment: You could also consider generating your C code. It might be as simple as writing a few dozen of lines of script (in python, awk, or whatever) to generate some C file containing your big `switch` statement. Many programs contain generating scripts for generated C code.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be a classical situation to use a key/value-storage like a hash table (in c there are e.g. [ghash](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Hash-Tables.html) and [uthash](https://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/)), where MyRequest.data (aka MyRequest.desiredDataId) would be the key and the DataValue.data would be the value. Your solution with the void pointer is pretty much the most trivial implementation to that: since all keys are integers, the hash-function is the identity function.

I am not sure why you are looking for an alternative, but if it is speed and you do find something that is faster than a hash-table I am sure the world would like to know. I think your void* solution is as fast as it gets (I expect that you are not actually working with char, int and float but that those are just examples, and that the long cast is an abstract form of something like a serialization routine - if it is not take a long-array, cast on assignment, and save the indirection).

If however, as I would guess, you don't want to have trouble with implementing the data-structure and maintaining it, you should be able to get a comparably fast solution using a hash-table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following requirements:

1. The `struct MyData` must have all data fields with different types, specific for each field.
2. The `MyRequest::desiredDataId` identifies a data field in a contiguous range or at least with very small gaps that could be filled with dummy fields.
3. The request must return `struct DataValue` with the field value converted to `long` in `DataValue::data`.
4. The code must not be repetitive.

I would suggest the following implementation:

```
class DataField {
public:
    virtual ~DataField() {}
    virtual long toLong() const = 0;
};

// Wrapper for T that implements toLong()
template <typename T>
class DataFieldImpl : public DataField {
public:
    DataFieldImpl() = default;
    DataFieldImpl(T v) : value(v) {} // implicit construction from T
    DataFieldImpl& operator=(T v) {  // direct assignment from T
        value = v;
        return *this;
    }
    operator T() const     {return value;} // implicit conversion to T
    const T& value() const {return value;} // const accessor
    T& value()             {return value;} // mutable accessor

    virtual long toLong() const {
        return static_cast<long>(value);
    }

private:
    T value;
};

struct MyData {
    static const size_t N = 370;
    DataField* data[N];

    // Implement constructor and destructor to create and destroy the fields.
} myData;

void doRequest(const MyRequest& request, DataValue* response) {
    if (request.desiredDataId < MyData::N) {
        response->data = myData.data[request.desiredDataId].toLong();
    }
}
```

About the "popular" `void*` solution: you can't convert `void` to `long`. That would require metadata information about each field indicating the type of each one and how to convert each `void*` to `long`, as plain simple `operator*` followed by cast to `long` wouldn't work. You can design those metadata and it would be a valid and efficient solution (and your only option in C). The virtual method and the template are actually just an implementation of those metadata using C++ language features. The overhead of virtual function call is (at least in theory) equivalent to fetching metadata in a C-like solution and equivalent to branching in the big switch statement (assuming proper compiler optimization of the switch clause).

Comment: thanks for the reply, although I'm not sure you noticed that any viable solution for my case should be C implementable, while your code requires classes, that is, C++ and the like! :) Well, event though your solution will be not be acceptable for me, certainly it was an useful contribution for the internet in general so, thanks anyway!